# Check if file exists yields error

Tags: windows, batch-file

All those countless questions on SO regarding this matter all suggest something like this:

```
if exists file.txt goto fileExist
echo file doesnt exist
:fileExist
echo file exists
```

However I can not get it to work. It always outputs

```
"file.txt" can syntactically not be processed at this location
```

(translated by me, no idea which words are used in the english windows version)

I tried `if exists "file.txt" [...]` and wrapping the yes case in `()`, all producing the same error.

Comment: Ever tried 'if exist' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common mistake.

I do it all the time myself.

The right keyword is `EXIST`, not `EXISTS`, notice the `s` at the end.

So:

```
if exists file.txt goto fileExist       <-- wrong
if exist file.txt goto fileExist        <-- right
```

Comment: Oh wow ... Seems like I need glasses. Thank you.

Comment: I have glasses, trust me, it won't help you avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: Text editors with syntax highlighting help.

Comment: As a SQL developer, I frequently have momentary confusion as I try to remember which syntax is used for which language: EXISTS for SQL, and EXIST for batch.